# Rails 3 HABTM - access intersection entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, polymorphic-associations, arel

I'm attempting to approximate a polymorphic relationship in Rails 3 has-and-belongs-to-many association (HABTM).

The intersection table (user_favorites) has these fields: user_id, favorite_id, favorite_class

In the User class, I have the relationship defined:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :favorite_users, :class_name => "User", :join_table => "user_favorites", :association_foreign_key => "favorite_id", :foreign_key => "user_id", :conditions => "user_favorites.favorite_class='User'"
```

For retrieving data, this works as expected.  Unfortunately, this definition won't add the favorite_class' value that I need ('User' in this situation).

Is there a way, perhaps using Arel, to set the favorite_class field to the desired value before the record is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the :insert_sql option (note use of single quotations):

```
:insert_sql => 'INSERT INTO user_favorites (user_id, favorite_id, favorite_type) VALUES (#{id}, #{record.id}, "User")'
```

Comment: Not downvoting but I recommend against this.  Rails depends on following the conventions.  doing sql inserts like this is a PHP approach that is not recommended for professional production code.

Answer (score 2):

A has_many through association might work better. Here's an article that may help. It explains the problem with a polymorphic has_many :through relationship, and offers a workaround.

http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/3/polymorphic-through

this might be helpful too:

[Polymorphic habtm relationships with Rails/ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123362/polymorphic-habtm-relationships-with-rails-activerecord)

Comment: +1 habtm doesn't allow extra fields for the join association.  It's frequently treated as deprecated, because changing the associations (from habtm to hmt) and code that uses them is a pain the first time an extra field is needed.  has_many :through allows this without those major mods.

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL injection in your variant. Better use in your UserFavourites model following:

```
before_save :set_favourite_type

private 

def set_favorite_type
  self[:favorite_type] = self.favoritable.class.to_s
end
```

or at least use parametrized query instead of #{}